# :remote => true confusion with form_for

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just learning Rails and would appreciate any help. I've looked at probably 10 tutorials for `:remote => true` on `form_for` and they all seem to copy each other (equally confusing).

This tutorial is one of them: http://tech.thereq.com/post/18910961502/rails-3-using-form-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs

My web app is pretty much all on one page, and my 'submit form' is inside a pop-up lightbox. This means that the form_for code is actually within my index.html.erb. It also means a new @playlist instance variable is created for `index` (instead of having this be in `new`)

**My end goal is this**:

`if @playlist.save` returns `true`, I want to REDIRECT the user to the `root_path` WITH a :notice. There is no need to update the form with a success message or anything like that. I want a hard redirect on save success.

`if @playlist.save` returns `false`, I want to render the code inside create.js.erb, which will append the errors into the lightbox form without refreshing the page. **note** A lot of the tutorials seem to want to re-render the entire form as html, then replace the contents in place. I'd rather (if I can), just send the errors to the form and insert them, I think re-rendering and replacing the entire form seems more complicated than it has to be.

**As of right now**, my code is kind of muddled, especially:

- the `respond_to` block. This is the largest point of confusion about what actually goes here, I have tried lots of different code and nothing works
- I have no idea if create.js.erb is correct
- I have no create.html.erb - I assume this is right because I just want to redirect

**First line of my form**:

```
<%= form_for @playlist, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

**My entire PlaylistsController**

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_genres, :only =>[:index, :user]
  before_filter :new_playlist, :only => [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @playlists = Playlist.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(30)
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if @playlist.save
        # ???
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Playlist submitted" }
      else
        # ???
        format.js { render :js => @playlist.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def user
    @playlists = Playlist.order('created_at DESC').where(:username => params[:username]).page(params[:page]).per(30)
  end

  def listen
    playlist = Playlist.find(params[:playlist_id])
    playlist.update_attribute(:listens, playlist.listens + 1)
    render :nothing => true
  end

  private

  def load_genres
    @genres = Genre.order(:name)
  end

  def new_playlist
    @playlist = Playlist.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url], :description => params[:description])
  end

end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('createjs called');
    $('#submit-form form').on('ajax:error', function(event, xhr, status, error){

        var responseObject = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), 
            errors = $('<ul />');

        $.each(responseObject, function(index, value){
            errors.append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        })

        $(this).find('.submit-playlist-errors').html(errors);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm actually a little confused about what you're struggling with, what you need to achieve. What's working and what's not. Could you simplify and break down your question?

Comment: Trust me I've tried to break it down before on other forums and whatnot. It's hard to explain, I tried to make it really clear what I'm looking for. As of right now it just doesnt work, period. I know the problem is with my respond_to block, mainly because I dont understand it and all the tutorials I've read are confusing about this topic

Comment: I've realized one error is that I had this: `@playlist = Playlist.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url], :description => params[:description])`. It should just be `params[:playlist]`. I will give the exact errors I'm getting in a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a form and you want to redirect with `flash` notice if the form is saved. If the form is invalid you want do display errors.

You can send the form (or any request) to rails app in different formats (usually html, json and js). This is specified in the url you provides.

```
playlist_path(@playlist)
# => /playlists/1

playlist_path(@playlist, :format => "json")
# => /playlists/1.json

playlist_path(@playlist, :format => "html")
# => /playlists/1.html
# ... etc
```

The format tells rails which kind of response specified in your `respond_to` block to use.

Now if this is clear you have to decide which format to use.

If you specify `js` format, the response will be treated as `script` an executed. If the form is valid, you can send user javascript that will redirect them to the page you desire. If the form is invalid, you can modify HTML in the way so you can display error messages. No client-side code needed.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if valid
    format.js { render "valid" }
  else
    format.js { render "invalid", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

# valid.js.erb
window.location = <%= your_path %>

# invalid.js.erb
// whatever to display errors
```

When you use `json` you can return redirect url to redirect user or errors if the form is invalid. Note that this solution requires Javascript on the client side to handle it.

```
# controller
respond_to do |format|
  if valid
    format.json { render :json => your_path }
  else
    format.json { render :json => @object.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

# client side javascript
$("form")
  .on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, response) {
    window.location = data
  })
  .on("ajax:error", function(event, response, error) {
    // logic to handle errors
  })
```

You can also use `html` format (by setting format to `html` or not specifying format at all). But if you use `:remote => true` you will have to treat it the same way as `json` (have client side javascript). If you use `redirect_to` as a response, it will redirect the request, not your user.

I am not sure about displaying the flash message after the user is redirected but you can try it this way:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if valid
    format.html { 
      flash[:notice] = "Playlist submitted"
      render :json => your_path }
  else
    format.html { render :json => @object.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

# client side javascript
//...
```

Hopefully this will dry your `respond_to` block.

Comment: Is there a way i can redirect without using javascript? like have the response the server sends back redirect them?

Comment: I am afraid there is no such way. You can simplify redirecting using javascript from your controller by calling `render :js => "window.location = #{your_path}"`.

Comment: I keep getting this error: !! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `bytesize' for :playlist_hash:Symbol
!! Unexpected error while processing request: deadlock; recursive locking

Comment: The first error seems like problems with params and the later like with database. But that is just a guess.